# How to use Templates inside JS file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates

I am trying to use javascript templates

```
<script type="text/x-tmpl" id="tmpl-demo">
   <h3>{%=o.title%}</h3>
   <p>Released under the
   <a href="{%=o.license.url%}">{%=o.license.name%}</a>.</p>
</script>
```

The problem is - I want to include this inside my JS file ? How would I go about using the templates but inside my JS file where I assume I cant use the `<script>` tag ?

Currently, I do something like:

```
myFunction(id) {
   return "<div>" + id + "</div>";
}
```

And I would like to convert that to templates instead?

Comment: Also - can someone suggest why the second method - with the `return` - is bad ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have basically four choices:

1. Include it as a string in the javascript file
2. Make this a little easier for yourself by preparsing the javascript file with a server side language
3. Using something like jammit, to dynamically create javascript files with the templates as variables, and include those.
4. Use requirejs and load the templates using the text plugin.